# Gathering feedback on performance as a Scrum Master

Tags: scrum, performance, feedback, scrum-master

As a ScrumMaster, what techniques would you recommend to gather feedback from the Team Members?

What criteria should the Team Members, the Product Owner and, other stakeholders take into account in order to assess the performance of the ScrumMaster?

Comment: That is a great question, kudos!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Evaluating Scrum Masters is one of the toughest challenges in my opinion, because if she does the job well nobody will really realize it, but when things go wrong, she will be first one held responsible.

> What criteria should the Team Members, the Product Owner and, other stakeholders take into account in order to assess the performance of the ScrumMaster?

**How much did she do for the team?** If you ask around and Scrum Team members, Product Owners tell you stories how much a Scrum Master did *for the project* then she is doing it wrong.

The primary purpose of the Scrum Master is to make sure that the work is done according to Scrum principles and the Scrum Team continuously improves itself. The project delivery is the responsibility of the Product Owner and the Scrum Team. If the colleagues tell you how much they've learnt from the Scrum Master and the Product Owner acknowledges that the new knowledge helped to move forward the project then she did a good job.

**Can the team use feedback in order to deliver quality product?** Scrum has a strong emphasis on the [fast] feedback and the Scrum Master's goal is to teach the team how to use feedback.

For example, if the Scrum Team is unable to deliver the commitment after the third Sprint and the next Sprint doesn't look good either then the Scrum Master does something wrong, because the Scrum Team failed to realize that something isn't going well and there are no positive differences in the way of working.

> As a ScrumMaster, what techniques would you recommend to gather feedback from the Team Members?

I would ask them to tell me - face to face - stories focusing on the two criterias from above.

Comment: Great answer! I like your approach, specially "how much they've learnt from the Scrum Master" +1

Comment: Thank you very much. It is important to recognize the difference between a real Scrum Master and a Team Leader who just got the title, but his daily tasks remained the same as they were before. In this case you cannot evaluate the Team Leader as I described...

Answer (score 0):

I find this article VERY helpful, it contains the questions to ask to your team or PO to collect feedback about the SM
http://illustratedagile.com/2015/03/24/how-to-capture-scrum-master-feedback

I transferred into a survery format, but f2f is better of course 
https://docs.google.com/a/raye7.com/forms/d/1mde10aWi-kVgyIiKic4-mTq_MxPGCRj9PEc0OEEdlzY/edit